# cannot find dynamic web project on eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

Tags: java, eclipse

i have already installed eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0), and installed the software Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development on my mac, yet the problem i face is that i cannot create a dynamic web project even after installing the required updates and restarting eclipse. This is because the option is just not there at all

Comment: Can you list all install steps you took so they can be reviewed?

Comment: yeah sure, all i did was the 'install new software' in the help section, entered the website ' Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen ' and then selected   'Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development'  for installation, after agreeing to the license agreement, i had to restart my eclipse. But i still didnt get the option when i went to file>other